# Solving differential equation using matrices

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to write down the first order equation system for the following differential equation
and solve it:

$$y'''+y''-2y'=0\\y''(0)=6,\,y'(0)=0,\,y(0)=3$$

Is the solution of this system stable? How should I use eigenvalues and matrices in this example?

Comment: Please do not post unsearchable images of equations.  Instead typeset using *MathJax*.  Thanks for fixing that.

Comment: What do you mean by stable? Also, since this equation is not in the form $y'=Ay$ where $A$ is a linear operator, I don't see how one could apply matrices to the question.

Comment: What have you tried? What are your issues to solve the problem?

Comment: Let $y_1=y$, $y_2=y^\prime$, $y_3=y^{\prime\prime}$.  Solve the first equation for $y^{\prime\prime\prime}=y_3^\prime.$  Now write a differential equation in matrix form:  $\mathbf{y}^\prime= A \mathbf{y}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y_1=y$, $y_2=y^\prime$, $y_3=y^{\prime\prime}$.  Solve the first equation for $y^{\prime\prime\prime}=y_3^\prime.$  Now write a differential equation in matrix form:  $\mathbf{y}^\prime= A \mathbf{y}$.

$$\begin{aligned}
y_1^\prime &= y_2\\
y_2^\prime &= y_3\\
y_3^\prime &=2y_2-y_3
\end{aligned}
$$

$$\mathbf{y}^\prime= A\mathbf{y}$$ with $$A=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&2&-1} $$

This (along with initial conditions) is an initial value problem with solution $\mathbf{y}=e^{A t} y(0)$

The characteristic equation of $A$ is $p(\lambda) = 2\lambda-\lambda^2 -\lambda^3=0$ so that the
eigenvalues of $A$ are $\{-2,0,1\}$.

By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $A$ satisfies its characteristic equation, so that

$$A^3=2A-A^2$$

We can use this to compute $e^{At}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(At)^k}{k!}:$

$$e^{A t} = \pmatrix{
1 & 
-\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{6} e^{-2t} + \frac{2}{3} e^{t} &
-\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{6} e^{-2t} + \frac{1}{3} e^{t} \\
0 & 
\frac{1}{3} e^{-2t} + \frac{2}{3} e^{t} &
-\frac{1}{3}e^{-2t} + \frac{1}{3} e^{t} \\
0 &
-\frac{2}{3} e^{-2t}  + \frac{2}{3}e^{t} &
\frac{2}{3} e^{-2t} + \frac{1}{3}e^{t} \\}$$

$$\mathbf{y}(t) = e^{At}\mathbf{y}(0)= \pmatrix{e^{-2t}+2e^{t} \\ 
-2 e^{-2t}+2e^{t}\\4e^{-2t}+2e^{t}}$$

And the scalar $y(t)$ is the first entry of the vector, $$y(t) = e^{-2t}+2e^t$$

Is it stable?  Well $y(t)\to \infty$ as $t\to \infty$.

**UPDATE, in response to the question about finding $e^{A t}$:**

$$I + A + \frac{A^2}{2!}+\frac{A^3}{3!} = \pmatrix{1&t+t^3/3&t^2/2-t^6/6\\ 0 & 1+t^2-t^3/3 & t -t^2/2+t^3/2 \\0 &2t-t^2+t^3&1-t+3t^2/2-5t^3/6}$$

We know that each element of $e^{A t}$ is a linear combination of $\{1,e^{-2t},e^t\}.$. Thus, we already have the first column.  Let's look at the first term in the second column.  We are looking for an entry of the form $\alpha + \beta e^{-2t} + \gamma e^{t}$.  There is no constant term.  This means that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0$.  The term associated with $t$ is $t$.  We have $e^{-2t} = 1  -2t +2t^2 -4t^3/6 +\cdots$ and $e^{t}=1+t+t^2/2+t^3/6+\cdots.$ Looking at the $t$ term, $-2\beta +\gamma=1.$  The term associated with $t^2=0$ so $2\beta+\gamma/2=0.$

So, on second thought, we don't even need the $t^3$ terms introduced by $A^3.$  That is because the matrix

$$B= \pmatrix{1 & 1 &1 \\ 0 & -2 & 1\\0 &2 &\frac{1}{2}},$$ from which we compute $\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}$ is non-singular.

Comment: could you, please, explain in more details about how you've found $e^{At}$?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the form of the equations guess a solution of the form $y(x) \propto e^{a x}(b + c \cos (d x))$.  Plug and chug to find:

$$y(x) = \frac{3}{5} e^{-x} (4 e^{2 x} + \cos (x) - 3 \sin (x))$$

which (from the $e^x$ term) is obviously unstable, as confirmed by its graph:

[image]

(In *Mathematica*)

Comment: You should mention the math software you used! Apart from that, I doubt that the answer will help to increase mathematical knowledge/understanding.